# Parallelize api calls in kotlin

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, asynchronous, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines

I need to asynchronously call 2 read operation from S3 then parse the data from S3.
Total record from both files are ~24k
Tried coroutines with async but each process triggers after a minute
Ex:

Initiate read from S3 for file 1 - started at 10:29:53
Parse Data for file 1            - started at 10:29:53

Initiate read from S3 for file 2 - started at 10:30:53
Parse Data for file 2            - started at 10:30:53

How can we parallelise both fetch from S3 operation and parsing for all files so that they **begin execution at same time i.e 10:29:53**

```
fun process() {
    runBlocking {
        async { parseFile("File1") }.await()
        async { parseFile("File2") }.await()

    }
}

private fun parseFile(fileName: String) {
    lon.info {"Initiate read from S3 for $fileName "}
    val getRecord = s3RepositoryClient.getObjectContentInputStream(fileName)
    val parseToString=parse(
        objectMapper, getRecord,"test"
    )
    parseToString.parallelStream().forEach {
        dynamoDbClient.save(it)
    }
}


fun parseToString(mapper: ObjectMapper, records: InputStream, textName: String): List<Billing> {
    var response: List<Billing> = emptyList()
    val reader = BufferedReader(records.reader())
    try {
        var line = reader.readLine()
        while (line != null) {
            response = response.plus(
                Billing.from(
                    mapper.readValue(line, Employee::class.java),
                    line,
                    textName
                )
            )
            line = reader.readLine()
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close()
    }
    return response
}
```

Comment: The wrapping `async {...}.await()` adds nothing, I think IntelliJ gives you a warning about that. To do things concurrently, do `async` `async` `await` `await`, instead of `async` `await` `async` `await`.

Comment: @George Leung you meant -                                                                                              async { parseFile("File1") }
async { parseFile("File2") }
awaitAll()
??

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems that cause this.

First, you `await()` on the first call before calling the second one. That means we can start the second one only after the first fully completes. To run both of them concurrently, we have to start them both and only then wait:

```kotlin
val deferred1 = async { parseFile("File1") }
val deferred2 = async { parseFile("File2") }
val result1 = deferred1.await()
val result2 = deferred2.await()
```

In your specific case, you don't even use results of these functions, so you don't have to await on them and we can/should use `launch()` instead of `async()`:

```kotlin
runBlocking {
    launch { parseFile("File1") }
    launch { parseFile("File2") }
}
```

Second problem is that by default `runBlocking()` uses a single thread and because your operations are blocking I/O, it can run only one of them at a time. To utilize multiple threads, use `Dispatchers.IO`:

```kotlin
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    launch { parseFile("File1") }
    launch { parseFile("File2") }
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks- all process- parseFile & parseToString seems to start at same time 2023-12-16T22:41:24.903+05:30 Although not sure why overall time take to complete both process has increased

Comment: I can only guess. Maybe the bottleneck here is the networking to S3, so by creating two streams you don't really gain anything and you even lose a little due to doing too much at the same time? Which makes sense, IO is usually much slower than data parsing.